# Sorting IBOutletCollection Array of TextFields According to frame.origin.y

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort array of `textFields` according to `frame.origin.y`. But when I ran simulator it got stuck. Any Idea?

```
IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFields
```

My code :

```
-(NSMutableArray *)bubbleSort:(NSMutableArray *) unsortedArray{
 NSInteger i,j;
 //NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
 for(i=0;i<unsortedArray.count;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(((UITextField *)[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i]).frame.origin.y > ((UITextField *)[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j]).frame.origin.y)
        {

            UITextField *temp=[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:i]; 
            [unsortedArray insertObject:[unsortedArray objectAtIndex:j] atIndex:i];
            [unsortedArray insertObject:temp atIndex:j];
        }
    }
  }
  //NSLog(@"%@",unsortedArray);
  return unsortedArray;
}
```

Comment: Where does it get stuck exactly? Did you try debugging it? Any exceptions? I would also suggest extracting variables in your code, it would help alot with the clarity and make it easier to debug.

Comment: return statement doesn't get executed. getting hung after couple of iteration of loop. No exceptions.

Comment: I'm getting bad EXEC after few minuets.

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Learner said, you just keep on inserting object in your array, so you never leave your outer for loop. To swap two elements, you can use

```
- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2
```

so in your case, inside your `if`, you can simply write

```
[unsortedArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
```

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB)

Answer (score 2):

look like this will keep on inserting object in array. so unsortedArray.count will keep increasing. in my opinion you need to remove object first and than insert it to upper rank or lower rank depending on algorithm.

se documentation for NSMutableArray insert object function.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html